# Cant reach AWS ElasticBeanstalk application via url even though environment health shows OK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have deployed my app successfully however I cant seem to access the app via the URL. Using the url generate by EB results in "site cannot be reached" being displayed by the browser. It attempts to load then hangs for about 30 seconds then retuns "Site cannot be reached"

Comment: How is your health check defined? Does your security group allow incoming traffic on ports 80/443?

Comment: Are you talking of the security group for the instances under the load balancer?

Comment: If you're using an elastic load balancer, then your ELB will need to accept incoming connections from anywhere on ports 80 and 443. Your instances will need to accept connections on port 80 from the ELB. Regardless, it'll be difficult to help you troubleshoot your issue without more information.

Comment: The ELB accepts HTTP connections on 80 from 0.0.0.0/0 while the target instances accepts request from the security group which the load balancer belongs to

Comment: That's not the problem then. What platform is your EB instance running? Is your application listening on port 80?